# How to tile an Image created in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: tiles

I'm a beginner in this and don't understand something.

I have a simple map in Adobe Illustrator, and I want to tiling it to using in webglearth (https://www.webglearth.com/). How I can do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can save the map from Adobe Illustrator as PDF or as TIFF with high resolution and then use [MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.com) to bring it to WebGL Earth quite easily. There is a [video tutorial that can be found here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=by5sTBs1qOA&list=PLGHe6Moaz52PiQd1mO-S9QrCjqSn1v-ay&index=1).

MapTiler even provide you with a WebGL Earth viewer for your map - the index.html.

All that you need to do is to upload the tiles to any web hosting site. Their [how to section on hosting](http://www.maptiler.com/how-to/hosting/) has a variety of possibilities.

The WebGL Earth has been developed by the same team who works on MapTiler as well...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunantly a map made in Adobe Illustrator is not really a map that can be used in a proper web mapping application. It does not contain any coordinates that would help to locate things on a globe.